# gridview on scrolling generates random click events

Tags: java, android, gridview

```
//ImageAdapter.java
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    String list_app_name[] = {"calendar","weather","news","youtube","time","gmail","gmap","twitter","facebook","hmb","uber","mirror_mode"};

    private final List<MyModel> items;
    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<MyModel> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {  
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        final MyModel item = items.get(position);

        // set value into imageview---------
        ImageView image = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(item_image);
        ToggleButton button_ = (ToggleButton) gridView.findViewById(R.id.item_button);

//        Log.d("adapter crash",list_app_name[position]);
        SharedStorage st = new SharedStorage(context);
        try {
            this.isAppSynced = st.getSyncedApps();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(isAppSynced.get(list_app_name[position])) {
            image.setImageResource(item.getItem_image());
        } else {
            image.setImageResource(item.getDown_image());
        }

        // set value into textview
        TextView text = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(item_text);
        text.setText(item.getItem_text());
        //------------------------------------------------------


        //the click listener for image and buttons are set here.    
        setClickListenerForImage(image,position);

        setClickListenerForButton(button_,position);

        return gridView;
    }
}



//MainActivity.java
//setting up the adapter for gridView
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.simpleGrid);

        //get the mitems list to be initialised with the images, text and other items to be rendered by the adapter.
        generateData();

        ia = new ImageAdapter(this,mItems);
        grid.setAdapter(ia);
        ...
    }
```

I am using a custom gridview with each item of the gridview having one ImageView, ToggleButton, TextView.

Out of these views ImageView and ToggleButton are to be clicked. So I have setup two click listeners for each of the item inside ImageAdapter.java.

The problem I am facing is that some particular item's ToggleButton gets clicked on its own while scrolling.

When I scroll the gridview the item gets clicked randomly and respective event takes place associated with the click listener of that particular item.

Comment: Please add code of setClickListenerForButton() method

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem by using recyclerview instead of gridview.